# Passing Parameter to SSRS Business Object Class Data Source

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, reporting-services, visual-studio-2013, ssrs-2008

I've created an SSRS report in VS2013 using MVC and [MVC Report Viewer](https://github.com/ilich/MvcReportViewer). The data source for the report is a class that has several methods which return Lists of different types of objects:

```
 public class ReportModel
{
     //known branchId for test purposes
     private static int branchId = 12345;

     public List<Top5Record> GetTop5()
    {           
       return (from s in context.Salesmen
       where s.branchId == branchId
       select new Top5Record
      {
         Name  = tr.Name,
         Sales = tr.Sales
      }).ToList();
    }
}
```

Now that I'm done testing, I need to make it so the branchId is passed in as a parameter instead of it being hard-coded. Since I don't directly create the ReportModel class, I don't see how I could pass the branchId in a constructor... unless there's something I'm not aware of.

My report url looks like this:

```
http://localhost/Branch/Report?branchId=1234
```

So I would ideally like to grab the branchId from the url and pass it to the ReportModel class somehow. Is this something that can be done?

All the info(like [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd220464.aspx)) I've found so far on SSRS parameters seems to revolve around parameters used at the designer level *after* the data has been retrieved from the data source.

If what I want to achieve is not possible, is there some clever workaround anyone can suggest? I'm pretty stumped at the moment on this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure out what I had to do to pass parameters to my methods.It turns out there was a native way to do this that I wasn't aware of. First, I had to change my methods to take parameters:

```
public class ReportModel
{

 public List<Top5Record> GetTop5(int branchId)
{           
   return (from s in context.Salesmen
   where s.branchId == branchId
   select new Top5Record
  {
     Name  = tr.Name,
     Sales = tr.Sales
  }).ToList();
}
}
```

Then I had to go to the page where I have my report viewer and open it in design mode. I selected the ObjectDataSource I wanted and in the properties menu clicked on the ellipsis for the SelectParameters option under the Data section. From there I clicked on "Add Parameter", gave it a name, and selected QueryString as the Parameter Source. I had to also set the QueryStringField which in my case was branchId. Now I can pass the branchId in the url queryString to my data source class and everything is right with the world. I wonder why there isn't more documentation on this.